# how to set a folder to save telethon sessions in it

Tags: python, telethon

I have a code:

```py
client = TelegramClient(
    "new_session", 
    api_id=CONFIG["client_api_id"], 
    api_hash=CONFIG["client_api_hash"]
)
```

so how i can save the "new_session.session" in another folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass the path to the client, relative or absolute.

```py
client = TelegramClient(
    "relative/path/to/new_session", 
    api_id=CONFIG["client_api_id"], 
    api_hash=CONFIG["client_api_hash"]
)
```

```py
client = TelegramClient(
    "/absolute/path/to/new_session", 
    api_id=CONFIG["client_api_id"], 
    api_hash=CONFIG["client_api_hash"]
)
```

To avoid errors by paths with `/` or `\` among different systems, I prefer to use the `pathlib` module.

```py
from pathlib import Path

client = TelegramClient(
    str(Path("path/to/new_session")), 
    api_id=CONFIG["client_api_id"], 
    api_hash=CONFIG["client_api_hash"]
)
```

The path to the session file must exist before trying to instantiate the `TelegramClient`.

Comment: But when I point the way like first one I get an error `self._conn = sqlite3.connect(self.filename,
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file`. I use this one: `client = TelegramClient("sessions/new_session1.session", api_id=CONFIG["client_api_id"], api_hash=CONFIG["client_api_hash"])`

Comment: And when i use with `Path` i get `TypeError: The given session must be a str or a Session instance.`

Comment: Just updated the example with `Path`, casting to `str` fix the issue with `telethon`. If you get the error, `sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file`, should be because the `session` folder does not exist. Create it first.

Comment: Also, edited to add a clarification about the paths. Please, if you fix the issue, mark the answer as correct.